# Is it possible to fire an event handler when the element is enabled or disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to execute a method when the input is enabled or disabled. Is it possible to do in jQuery?

I want to do something similar to this ( `non-working code below` ):-

```
$('input').on('enabled', function(e){
   alert( 'Just now someone enabled : ' + $(this).attr('id') );
   executeSomeHandlerForENABLED();
}).on('disabled', function(e){
   alert( 'Just now someone disabled : ' + $(this).attr('id') );
   executeSomeHandlerForDISABLED();
});
```

Comment: How do you enable or disable the input???

Comment: @Kangkan No it is not working. Edited the question if it created some confusion.

Comment: @asifsid88  There can be various events on which these inputs ( assume checkbox ) can be enabled and disabled.

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is!  For modern browsers the proper way to do this is with [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).  Unfortunately not even IE10 supports MutationObservers, never mind IE8 and 9.  In order to support IE 8-10, you'll need to fire the propertychange event yourself when the disabled is set, and to do that you'll need to change the getters and setters on the elements that you want to enable/disable.

Here are a couple of good articles about this technique:

- [MSDN getter/setter article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd229916%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN getter/setter examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd548687%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Unfortunately you can't just use the native fireEvent on a disabled event within the setter, because it obeys the disabled state.  Therefore we need an external event triggering system.  Luckily for us the good folks at jQuery have already done that!

So, with that knowledge I wrote a [fireOnDisable](https://gist.github.com/cmcnulty/7036509) jQuery plugin.  To use it, simply apply it to the selector eg:

```
$('#disabled_thing').fireOnDisable();
```

If you are in a browser that doesn't natively support propertychange events, this plugin will do nothing.  It's exclusively for IE8-10.  For IE7 or lesser, you're screwed, because they don't expose the setter/getter functions.

Comment: Thanks for replying after 6 months ;) ( kidding ).    Yeah `MutationObserver` will do the job [ Chrome had this since long ).  Btw, mine was easy case. I knew that some innocent developer is using jQuery to disable and enable the button. But I was unable to find that code. So I changed the code in jQuery.js , that gave me the exact position where it was getting disabled/enabled.   [ And yes Nice jQuery plugin,  upvoting for that ]

Answer (score 1):

**YES,** but what you are trying is not an easy task.

What you can do is, use `propertychange` event (which by the way is not available on IE) to catch the change in properties.

I googled and found [this](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/) solution implemented. A plugin to watch the property as it changes. For IE it fallbacks to `setTimeout()` which is very sad indeed.

Anyways, your solution utilizing that solution would be something like:

```
$("input").watch('disabled', function() {
    console.log($(this).is(":disabled"));
});
```